# Power Automate flow to create a work item 'issue' if the work item 'risk' state is moved to 'occurred' in DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, devops, power-automate

Power Automate flow to create a work item 'issue' if the work item 'risk' state is moved to 'occurred' in DevOps. Also, if any field of the same work item 'risk' is modified in future (keeping the state as occurred) then it should not create any new work item 'task'. I tried below shown flow. but it create a new Issue whenever there's an update it the work item 'risk'. Any kind of assistance is appreciated.

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7FNe.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fkq0R.jpg)

Tried the flow shown in the image.

Comment: Hi, have you checked and tested to see whether my suggestion works?

Answer (score 0):

Tested by my side, you can add a second Condition2 by setting "State Changed Date" equals to "Changde Date" then the Issue WIT will be created, it means that only when the Changed date equals to State Changed Date, then the WIT will be created. Like the pics below.

Pic 1:
[image]

Pic 2:
[image]

Test results:
When editing the specified Risk WIT, then it would not create any new Issue WIT then.

You can check and have a test.